# Web Analytics Connector and LinkName

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've recently setup Web Analytic Connector (WAC).  I'm now trying to customize the WAC string to return a static value in the **utm_contact** parameter when no link alias is assigned.  By default this parameter returns the URL of the link.

Here is the initial code used, which does successfully deploy the email.

```
&utm_content=%%linkname%%
```

When I make the following edits, the email job cancels.

```
&utm_content=%%=iif(IndexOf(linkname,"http")>0, linkname,"unknownlink")=%%
```

I've used custom ampscript in the WAC strings before, but never in reference to the linkname personalization string.  Is this possible?  Any suggestions on how I might customize the **utm_content** output?

**update**

SFMC Support provided the following details on the email job that was cancelled after the WAC update.

```
MemberID: xxxxxxxxx JobID: yyyyy OMMSlotID zzzzzz 
ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException: An error occurred when attempting to resolve a function call. See inner exception for detail.
Function Call: iif(IndexOf(linkname,"http")>0, linkname,"unknownlink")
Index: 208
Content Type: Text
Substitution Level: Subscriber
Message Context: Unknown
Error Code: OMM_SCRIPT_SYNTAX_ERR
- from OMMCommon --> 

--- inner exception 1---

ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException: An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
Script Expression: IndexOf(linkname,"http")
MemberID: xxxxxxxxx
JobID: yyyyy
Error Code: OMM_SCRIPT_SYNTAX_ERR
- from OMMCommon --> 

--- inner exception 2---

ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionException: The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
Function Call: IndexOf(linkname,"http")
Attribute or Field Name: linkname
Error Code: OMM_FUNC_SYNTAX_ERR
- from OMMCommon
```

Comment: Is the alias (linkname) assigned via an AMPScript va, SSJS var or personalization string?  If so, I don't think this will work, judging from my interpretation of the docs. From Docs: `Link alias values generated via personalization strings, AMPScript, or SSJS does not reflect in the %%linkname%% value.`  (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)

Comment: The alias in my email is static text for one link and not supplied for the other.  In the WAC string, I am not trying to set the value for %%linkname%%, just read and use it in an ampscript function.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Gortonington for you comment.  I took a closer look at the online documentation. There must be something special to this personalization string. The documentation states, "This personalization string is only available in use with the web analytics connector."

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to solve for my issue.  But, I believe I've confirmed why it doesn't work.

I made the following update to my WAC string.

```
&utm_content=%%=iif(IndexOf(AttributeValue("linkname"),"http")>0, AttributeValue("linkname"),"unknownlink")=%%
```

I was able to successfully deploy emails after the update.  But, all the links in my email had a **utm_content** value of "undefinedlink".  To me, this means **linkname** must not yet be defined at the point this ampscript executes.